# Error while running exported Slick2d project

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d, jarsplice

I followed this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5stQZqOAM70 tutorial online. (exported to runnable jar file, then made jar file with jarsplice). I included all the necessary jars and natives like he explained, but when I try to run the application I get an alert box that says this: LoadLibrary failed with error 1114.

Please speak up if you need to see any files or code. Help me! I am using Eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, managed to "fix" my problem. The problem was not with the jar file itself, but with my computer. Turns out Java 1.8 has some problems on the intel 3000 graphics card, which is the one I have. I downgraded to 1.7 and the runnables are now working perfectly ;) Sent the jar to a friend of mine, and he was also able to run it without problems